Can I float an SLA 12v battery at 13.8V forever?
I am considering a battery-backup power source for a radio. Typically, power would be supplied through a standard 13.8V power supply, so the battery would be available if mains power goes out:
AC -> 13.8V linear supply --+--> Radio
                            |
                       SLA 12V Battery

I have read that a sealed lead acid battery will self-regulate its charge-current if you provide it with about 13.8V (at 25C).
What I have not found, however, is whether it is safe to leave it at 13.8V, or if you need to disconnect it after having charged the battery, in which case a more complicated charging circuit would be necessary.

Can I float an SLA 12v battery at 13.8V forever?
If so, would it reduce the life of the battery?


This is exactly what they do in cars and it works as long as you limit the charging current to some sane value (in a car, the alternator does this naturally). If you want some more battery life, reliability or other interesting features, better off the shelf solutions do exist.

Short answer: yes, it is safe to float a consumer-grade SLA for long periods of time at 13.8V if you don't live in a hot climate. They're designed to slowly vent the hydrogen that's produced (very slowly) as they self-discharge -- so their casings won't bulge, nor will the vented hydrogen present a significant fire risk, so long as you limit the charging current.  See https://content.nfpa.org/-/media/Project/Storefront/Catalog/Files/Research/Research-Foundation/Reports/RFLeadAcidBattery.pdf?rev=035c861de5bc4334be6b17e962d505aa -- where this class of batteries is described (formally, and more correctly) as a VRLA -- "valve-regulated lead acid".
Limiting the charging current will require some additional circuitry -- and you'll find some ideas in the other answers to your question.
You also asked whether this charging regime will cause any degradation in the life-expectancy of your battery. The answer is yes it will.  How much?  That'll depend on the battery's temperature and on a host of other factors... but I'd guess your battery will last for years unless you're thrashing it in some other way than by never fully charging it.  The issue at hand is sometimes called "soft sulfation" in the non-technical literature.  It'll build up, very slowly, over time -- but is mostly dissipated whenever you fully charge the battery. See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378775303010681:
"Lead sulfate accumulation on the negatives: This is the natural consequence of hydrogen evolution from the negative plates that eventually vents out of the batteries. This loss of hydrogen results in a charge imbalance between the positive and negative electrodes. Since the batteries are sealed and an equalization overcharge is not easy to do, this effect will result in a gradual loss of capacity and eventual failure."

Hello Clark, and welcome to this site! :-)

In addition to the solid answer about the float voltage, you have to consider what happens if the AC power returns when the battery is partially discharged. You can float an SLA battery at 13.8 or 14.0 V but you can't charge it with a 13.8 V high current fixed supply. When the battery is nearly empty and the power is turned on, it will simply blow the main battery fuse or trip the PSU..
For lower power applications, the usual solution is something like this, with the CC/CV charger set to an appropriate rate for your battery:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
But this isn't really appropriate for > 10 A loads.
Above this it depends on the relative size of your battery and your radio.

If the battery is (say) 200 Ah so it can comfortably absorb 40 A, and the radio needs 25 A, then set the charger current limit to 40 A and forget about it.
If the radio needs 25 A on transmit and the battery is 50 Ah, set the charger to 15 A and let the battery add the other 10 A. It shortens its life to do this, but not by very much, unless you're in a contest 24/7

There are other more complex solutions involving two full-current switchmode converters, found in off-grid solar systems, RV and camper second-battery systems, and boat inverters that accept solar, generators, shore power.

100W radio, so probably should plan for 15A peak.  IIRC, 100W TX moves the meter needle on the linear supply to about 12A.  Also I have more than one radio on the power bus, but don't think I've ever transmitted simultaneously. Battery is 2x 9Ah duracell SLA12-9F2 in parallel.

So you're in the awkward zone. Batteries can produce 15 A but probably only want to charge at max 2 A each. Maybe a couple of beefy Schottky diodes in parallel would be OK for you. See edit to the drawing for a charger.

Can you propose a common part for U1? BTW, power supply is Samlex 1235M. The PS doesn't appear to be adjustable, it is always 13.8V without hacking internals.  What did you mean regarding the 14.0V PSU in the lower schematic?  Does that D-R circuit replace U1?

@KJ7LNW Like I described in my answer, drop the float charge voltage to 13.50V or so if you want to do this plan and not want to accelerate the battery aging any more than necessary. I would use a p-ch MOSFET (in place of D2) to engage the battery to the load, and use a Schottky diode (D3 and R1) to drop the charging voltage to 13.50V.

@KJ7LNW if you're building this as a one-off, and the voltages don't add up, consider charging/floating using a low cost off-the-shelf buck-boost converter with a current limit. Often sold as LED drivers. I use a "20 A" one for DC-DC charging, eg my camping LiFePO4 needs 14.2 V to finish charging, but my car runs at 13.7 while driving, and there's the cable resistance. Watch out a) boost converters can't limit the current if Vin>Vout. b) divide the claimed current by Pi, or Pi/2 if you add a fan. c) think about all standard operation modes, abnormal, and total failures, add diodes and fuses!

Lead acid batteries are robust but their use life depends on the level of care built in the system. Float charging at 13.8V (2.30V/cell) is on the high side, which may be okay if your battery is always in the cold environment but that voltage is too high (reduces the lifespan) if the battery can be above "room temperature" say above 25C. You want to drop the voltage further, or disconnect the charging circuit after 24 or 48 hours of float charging at that voltage.
https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-403-charging-lead-acid
Look at their Figure 3 and its caption above the figure.
You could use a MOSFET or Schottky diode to switch the supplies.
I had (actually still have) a piece of non-radio equipment powered by lead acid (absorbed glass mat), and I had it on a charger that cuts off until the terminal voltage goes below a threshold so that the battery is automatically topped up after use. That charging logic is gentler than float charging while serving the same function. Those cells significantly declined after a year of use and became virtually useless by year 2. Eventually, I custom-fitted LiFePO4 cells to replace, with the charger adjusted for the chemistry (again, CC/CV charge and cutoff until the voltage goes below a threshold). This worked much better for my situation; I haven't replaced the cells since then. Thus, I found LiFePO4 batteries suitable for long-term backup solutions because of their low self-discharge rate and fairly reliable chemistry. LiFePO4's "weakness" is that it is difficult to determine the state of charge by looking at the terminal voltage since it is fairly constant.
One big advantage of using lithium batteries (LiCoO2,
LiFePO4 or another chemistry) for backup power is that lithium cells work well in under-charged states without shortening the battery life (in fact, the battery's life is considerably longer if the cell is not fully charged). Of course, the battery voltage must be above the lowest discharge voltage. Lead acid batteries must maintain a certain voltage near full charge state to maximize the life; both use life and storage life.
I have a deep cycle lead acid battery that I used to use as a backup supply for portable operation. I charge that battery every 6 months, even when I don't use it (and fully charge right after each use), and it is still in decent condition after nearly 10 years. If I treated that battery like the non-radio equipment above (AGM battery used in the factory kit), it would've deteriorated much faster.
Addendum / responding to tomnexus's answer
The following circuit would eliminate the voltage drop due to the series diode (his D2) when operating on the battery. Choose R to limit the charging current. The maximum float charge voltage is dropped to 13.5V by the same Schottky diode. The gate bias resistor is noncritical and can be anything reasonable.
The battery must be initially charged to a reasonable state (13+V terminal voltage) before connecting to avoid the MOSFET's body diode conducting.

The same thing can be done with LiFePO4 (4S pack with a BMS), even more effectively.

Love the comparison with Lithium cells. I would have suggested the same, especially if things need to be portable (as in: carry with your hands), because the energy density and power density is just so much higher with Lithium than lead acid. Also, self-discharge is so low, you can practically ignore having to charge them between uses if you remember to recharge after use. I have numbers around 1% to 3% of self-discharge per month in my head for them, so unless you forget them in a drawer for 15 years, you really don't benefit much from even having a charger that continuously "tops them up".

Keep in mind topping up lithium cells is one easy way to kill the cell fast. The art of prolonging the life of lithium cells is to start with a larger capacity than needed and not fully charge unless the absolutely longest runtime is required.

absolutely, but say you need some 100 VAh in energy, and you buy a 150 VAh battery pack, you can always charge it to 90% and keep it in a drawer for literal years without having to worry. I wouldn't go that route, though. Fully charge it. If it only has 80% of original capacity after 5 years, so be it – that's still enough; what's the point of having capacity you never use? (and also, I'm not too involved with batteries these days, but I think the rapid aging at full charge isn't nearly as bad as it used to be with early Lithium cells! Look where cellphone batteries are now, compared to 2010!)

It is not the rapid charging, but rather the terminal voltage that deteriorates the lithium cells fast, particularly with LiCoO2 (lithium-ion/polymer cells), where the full cycle life can easily be 2x or 3x by charging to well below 4.20V/cell. Less affected with LiFePO4 but still not fully charging can prolong by 1.5x or possibly 2x. This principle is commonly used in EVs and commercial power backups like those used in cellular towers.

didn't say it was the rapid charging, you must have misread my comment there!

The improvement you alluded to is largely from the improvement of the charging circuits and the control logic. Cellular phones, laptop computers, etc., of today, use a Coulomb counter to keep track of the state of charge accurately and precisely control the charging. More recently, usage pattern data has been used so as not to charge too much when low usage is anticipated.

nope, not just charging circuitry and control; there's really been leaps in materials and manufacturing of cells.

(I mean, compare commercially available cells now and 15 years ago. The printed-on capacity doesn't benefit from charging technology; just as capacity increased, with the same progress you can keep capacity constant and increase longevity.)

In fact, I still use several iPod 5.5G and 6G (the full-size iPod with video player functionality), with the HDDs replaced with flash memory. Of course, I custom-fit the latest lithium-ion cells that fit in the extra space I have. But the charger circuit is still the rather dumb one from the mid-2000s. The battery cells deteriorate faster in those than I would expect from a better charging logic of today.

I keep track of lithium chemistry progression with interest. What you wrote sounds like marketing copy to me. The anode degradation due to oxidation or interphase formation is the fundamental mechanism and that is directly accelerated by the cell terminal voltage. In order to slow that down, you would only have to give up about 20 to 30% of nominal full capacity. Even 10 or 15% less can still buy a significant improvement. This principle is very commonly used in commercial/professional equipment though much less so in consumer electronics, although it has become more common even in the latter.

https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC5452304/pdf/materials-06-01310.pdf

I'm not quite that marketing level untouched, my studies (a decade ago) did encompass battery chemistry lectures and talking to professors on that, I just never specialized in that. I do have a dear friend (chemistry) working for the battery acquisition unit of a larger German motor company, and he basically told me that with the improved chemistry and manufacture processes, you now see all the process variations as reliability issues, whereas fifteen years ago, cells were more uniformly worse than they are today :) It'd be a surprise to me, and I think to you as  well, if fifteen years in a

…relatively young field, with investments in the hundreds of billions for EV and for mobile devices, little substantial progress was made. :)

Lithium ion battery chemistry was invented in the 1970s and the current LiCoO2 chemistry was proposed around 1980. The commercial cells were made around 1990 and my cellular phone in the 1990s had LiCoO2 cells. The challenge is still centered around the anode durability: the solid-electrolyte interphase layer formation. https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/2021/cp/d1cp00359c

Controlling the material inputs and the process variation using statistical analysis is the very basic foundation of quality engineering practiced since the 1940s in the US and 1950s in Japan. The more details in the mechanism and cause-effect relationships we learn, the more variables we can measure and control.

Incidentally, the more I learn about lithium battery chemistry, the less confidence I have in the current implementations of EVs, perhaps except for regions where hydroelectric power is overabundant like Sweden. Lithium-ion (and LiFePO4 to some extent) is much better suited for portable electronics than large-scale applications, including transportation.

There's one more factor to consider: lead acid batteries depend on current flow to keep the plates conditioned.
If a battery stands for a long time with little or no current (charging or discharging), as on a prolonged float charge, the plates will build up a layer of lead sulfate which prevents current flowing when it's needed.  A "sulfated" liquid electrolyte cell can often be revived by supplying additional sulfate ions (either new acid, or adding a sulfate mineral such as epsom salt to the electrolyte), but this isn't practical to do with SLA type, as the electrolyte in these is gelled to prevent spillage.

Sulfation is a problem that occurs when the cell is left in the discharged state. If fully charged, that is not a problem. It is usually best practice to fully charge lead acid cells every few months to top up for that reason. High float charge voltage wears out the battery through a different mechanism.

I've seen examples of sulfated batteries after being on float charge for several months -- but perhaps they were already sulfated before they were left on float.  One of several reasons lead-acid isn't my favorite battery chemistry...

Lead acid is not my favorite chemistry, either. Some of the cells can deteriorate unevenly while on the charge and sulfate, too, because lead acids usually don't use BMS and rely on the current passing through the cell when some of the series cells are full. I much prefer NiMH or Lipo. LiFePO4 4S is very convenient for nearly drop-in replacement for lead acid 6S as well.

Of course, the reason we still have lead-acid everywhere is simple: cost.  Though with what parts stores are charging now for a new car battery, I could get a lithium replacement for only about 25% more...

Lead acid can supply a very large peak current, like starting a car. LiFePO4 and NiMH are not particularly strong in that department (though it improved in LiFePO4 over the last 10-15 years). If you actually calculate the cost per capacity and use life measured in charge cycles, LiFePO4 has been cheaper than lead acid for some years already. The thing is, the lead acid batteries can't hold capacity over many charge-discharge cycles, making it more expensive than it seems.

There are commercial lithium batteries now sold as drop-in replacement for car and deep-cycle marine/RV batteries -- at prices not much higher than lead-acid with a 2 year warranty.  Guess what's going in my car next time I need a replacement (1-2 years at most).
